# Empty promise object value from POST curl in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, curl, promise

I have the following Curl code in JavaScript :

```
function login() {
    var obj;
    const outputElement = document.getElementById('output');

  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api-keys', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('john@gmail.com:123456'),
    "content-type": "application/json"
  }
}).then(function(response) {
    obj = response.json();
    }).then(() => {
        outputElement.textContent = obj;
    })
    
}
```

but the element with `id = output` prints this :

```
[object Promise]
```

And if I print it in the `console`, with the same code as before but adding this instead :

```
...
.then(function(response) {
        obj = response.json();
        }).then(() => {
           console.log(obj);
        })
...
```

I get this :

[image]

And when I expand the arrow to the left of `PromiseResult`, I get this :

```
user_id: 2
user_name: john
created_at: "2024-01-04T04:01:03.855Z"
address: "Some address"
```

Which is what I want, but I cannot print it or store it, it's only available in the console.

Comment: I think you are trying to save the `obj` before the promise is fulfilled but I can't tell since the code calling login() is not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `response.json()` *[returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json#return_value)* a(another) `Promise` so you will require another `then` to handle the resolved data. Something like:

```js
function login() {
    // ...rest

    return fetch(
    // ...rest of your code
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json(); // return the promise
    }).then(function(data) { // <-- Notice this another then to handle data
        console.log(data); // log the data to the console
        outputElement.textContent = JSON.stringify(data); // display the data in the output element
    });
}
```